# Ubuntu server cron.d file not working - newbie question

Tags: ubuntu, cron, foswiki

I have created the below file in /etc/cron.d/

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   81 2011-07-10 14:56 foswiki
```

...and copied the below into the file:

```
* * * * * cd /var/lib/foswiki && perl -I bin tools/mailnotify -user AdminUser -q
```

I assumed that this would run every minute. It does not appear to run at all however.  The script is part of a Foswiki installation (likely irrelevant to the question) and does run manually, which leads me to think I've done something wrong in setting up the above.  Is it a file permissions issue?  Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For system-wide (non-user) crontab files, you need to specify a username to run the command with its permissions. For example:

```
* * * * * root cd /var/lib/foswiki && perl -I bin tools/mailnotify -user AdminUser -q
```

The above example will run your comman with the permissions of the *root* user, if you want to change that replace *root* with some other username.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. In this case it had no effect however. Useful to know though. Thanks.

Comment: Make your file executable: **chmod 0755 /etc/cron.d/foswiki**.

Comment: Thanks, Still no luck. I guess it's something else that's the problem. I'll close this. unresolved. Thanks.